# How can I change input from integers to characters?

Tags: java

I have tried changing `int` to `String` and `char` but neither seemed to work. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your phrase: ");
        int phrase =  input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered " + phrase);

        // closing the scanner object
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `String phrase = input.next();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `nextInt()` method attempts to get the next token as an `int`. If it is not an `int`, an `InputMismatchException` is thrown. If you enter input that can be represented as an `int`, then you will see your phrase printed.

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your phrase: ");
        String phrase = input.next();
        System.out.println("You entered " + phrase);

        // closing the scanner object
        input.close();
    }
}
```

`next()` returns the next complete token as a `String`.

[java.util.Scanner documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())

As Lino has pointed out, if you intend on capturing multiple, seperated words, you can instead use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

Comment: Depending on the use case `nextLine()` may be more favorable